# Searching for string within a text file in R

Tags: r, text-files

Is there an R function that would search for s string within a text file? Something like unix grep?

I guess the alternative will be to read the file line by line but was wondering if that can be bypassed by such a function?

Comment: Does that grep work on a file? Can you give an example?

Comment: Well you can pass the `grep` command that you would run from a terminal into the `system` function.

Comment: This isn't really about recommending software. It's just about grep.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**1)** Read it in and use R's `grep`:

```
 # test input
 cat("a 1\n\b 2\nc 3\n", file = "myfile.dat")


 grep("a", readLines("myfile.dat"), value = TRUE)
 ## [1] "a 1"
```

**2)** Another possibility if you have grep on your system and on the search path is:

```
 shell("grep a myfile.dat")
 ## a 1
```

On Windows you could use `findstr` in place of `grep` or if you have Rtools installed but not on your path `shell("C:\\Rtools\\bin\\grep a myfile.dat")`.  Change the path as needed.