# R source file for acf function

Tags: c, r

The `acf` function in R's stats library includes the line

```
.Call(C_acf, x, lag.max, type == "correlation")
```

but I can't find the file `C_acf` anywhere on my machine (nor at https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source nor https://github.com/wch/r-source).

Applying the advice at these questions didn't help:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254227/manual-calculation-of-acf-of-a-time-series-in-r-close-but-not-quite

[How to see the source code of R .Internal or .Primitive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function)

The file doesn't appear to be anywhere where people say to look. How can I find C_acf?

Comment: [Line 143 here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/library/stats/src/filter.c)? I think the `C_` is dropped, as it is for `pnorm` in Ben Bolker's [answer here on the question you link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14035586/903061)

Comment: Ah ha!  But how did you know to look in the file filter.c?

Comment: I searched the github repository for "acf", in the languages sidebar on the left I filtered the results to C. There were 5 results, and upon inspection the first one was correct.

Answer (score 6):

This method will help identify the source code of the compiled function which has class of `CallRoutine` or `NativeSymbolInfo`.

Find the namespace of the call routine

```
getAnywhere(C_acf)
# namespace:stats
```

Download your version of the base R, because stats is part of the base R.

```
download.file(url = "https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.0.0.tar.gz", destfile = "./R-3.0.0.tar.gz")
untar(tarfile = "./R-3.0.0.tar.gz", exdir = "./")
```

handle directory paths

```
old_dir <- getwd()
setwd("./R-3.0.0/src/library/stats/src/")
```

find the word `acf` in source files. You have to go through the list of results and identify the exact function. The easiest way is to look at the function name and its arguments.

```
myresults <- sapply( list.files("./"), function(x) grep("acf", readLines(x), value = TRUE))
myresults <- myresults[lengths(myresults) != 0]
myresults[2] 
# $filter.c
# [1] "acf0(double *x, int n, int ns, int nl, int correlation, double *acf)"
# [2] "\t\tacf[lag + d1*u + d2*v] = (nu > 0) ? sum/(nu + lag) : NA_REAL;"     
# [3] "\t    se[u] = sqrt(acf[0 + d1*u + d2*u]);"                            
# [4] "\t\tacf[0 + d1*u + d2*u] = 1.0;"                                       
# [5] "\t\t\tacf[lag + d1*u + d2*v] /= se[u]*se[v];"                           
# [6] "SEXP acf(SEXP x, SEXP lmax, SEXP sCor)"                              
# [7] "    acf0(REAL(x), nx, ns, lagmax, cor, REAL(ans));"
```

reset old directory path

```
setwd(old_dir)
```

**Reference:**

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)
- [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34708875/1691723)